# "git pull origin master" is opening emacs since I installed gited

Tags: git, emacs

I installed `gited.el` some time ago, and since, when I run `git pull origin master`, it runs the pull, finishes, and then opens emacs. The weird thing is that it doesn't always do it, and it doesnt do it in every folder.

Additionally, it only happens when there are new changes that get pulled (as in the branch is not up to date).

Anyone have any idea why this might be taking place? Anything about `gited` that might trigger this? Ideally I'd like it to stop.

Comment: The editor is invoked when it's a true merge, which creates a merge commit that needs you to edit the commit message. If it's a fast-forward merge, the editor won't come up. This might be the reason. You could try `git pull origin -r master` to avoid merge commits, or try `git pull origin --no-edit master` to avoid editing the commit message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The behavior of launching an editor on merge is expected in git.  It happens on pull *if* the pull results in a "true merge" (i.e. new commits from upstream that are not rebased and onto which the local branch cannot fast-forward), as it wants you to edit the commit message for the merge commit being created in that scenario.

One thing I suppose might have changed is what editor git launches.  In a typical install the default is some variant of `vi`, but this can be configured.  Since gited is essentially emacs integration for git, it's reasonable that it might have changed your core.editor (or equivalent environment) value to emacs.

If you can determine where this configuration was set, you can change it back.  This would also affect what editor you see whenever making a commit manually, etc., so maybe you want to change it, or maybe not.

But the thing is, all of this supposes that in scenarios where you now get emacs, you already previously were getting *some* editor.  I think that's likely true, but what you're saying suggests that you think it's not.

One reason you might not have seen this before would be if you previously were configured in a way that pull never generated merge commits.  For example, if you have `pull.rebase` set to true, then `pull` would not perform a true merge and would not need to create a merge commit.  Perhaps around the time you installed gited your `pull.rebase` value changed (though off hand I don't know why gited would change it).

If you want to allow `pull` to perform true merges, but don't want to see an editor, you can instruct git to use the default merge commit message without offering an editor

```
git pull --no-edit
```

Comment: Great answer, thank you. I haven't made any changes to anything, so it must have been something `gited` did behind the scenes, as you said. Still, this clears things up.

Comment: `git config --list --show-origin | grep core.editor`